# Snyder's Lorentz invariant discrete space-time

Tags: geometry, discrete, lorentz-symmetry, lattice-model

Can theories which say space-time is fundamentally discrete be compatible with Lorentz invariance? And if the answer is yes, in what sense is space-time no longer continuous?

I'm sure this has been asked in various forms before, but I wanted to ask in the context of this:
"Quantized Space-Time"
Hartland S. Snyder
Phys. Rev. 71, 38 – Published 1 January 1947
http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.71.38

Abstract:

> It is usually assumed that space-time is a continuum. This assumption is not required by Lorentz invariance. In this paper we give an example of a Lorentz invariant discrete space-time.

Searching for Synder on physics stackexchange didn't bring up anything relevant to this.

Unfortunately the paper is behind a paywall, so I've only seen the abstract.  Searching around I can't find much on Synder spaces except in discussions of non-commutative space-time.  Which I wouldn't really call discrete. Discrete brings to mind a lattice, or possibly irregular graph of spacetime events as nodes. So it is possible the technical meaning of the word discrete as used here may mean something other than "non-continuous" (but I'm hoping not since the abstract uses the word continuum), or maybe I don't understand the implication of non-commutative geometry. In other words, explanation of terminology would be much appreciated, and unfortunately may even be the only depth this possibly misguided question needs to be discussed to give an adequate answer.

Comment: This also looks like it could be interesting, as it discusses classical physics, hopefully allowing intuition to evolve before jumping to quantum mechanics. "Classical dynamics on Snyder spacetime" S. Mignemi, Int. J. Mod. Phys. D, 24, 1550043 (2015) http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0673 ... just started reading it.

Comment: Quantized doesn't mean the same thing as discrete. It means that distance or area measurements may be quantized. In a seminar talk Gert Binnig (the German scanning microscopy Nobel winner) once presented a discrete model (an automaton?) that he claimed had Lorentz symmetry. I have never seen a paper about the details, but he gave it as part of his talk on "creativity", so it may be explained in his book "Aus dem Nichts. Über die Kreativität von Natur und Mensch". It may have been about this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/887/relativistic-cellular-automata. Is this physics? No....