# Loop-quantum gravity as cellular automaton

Tags: loop-quantum-gravity, cellular-automaton

I've been reading [Zakopane lectures on loop gravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3660) lately and I only understood a very small part of it, but from the little I understood, I'm wondering if **loop quantum gravity** isn't close to describing the universe as some kind of **cellular automaton**.

The paper talks about space-time being considered as composed of grains connected by a graph. The way I understand it, the grains have a minimal size and can grow by steps (similar to the energy level of an electron in an atom). The size could be considered as a property of the cell (that would have many others).

A cell can impact the ones next to him and the effect of the 'content' of a cell can therefore propagate around it.

Of course, the automaton would have to be 'quantic' in the sense that its properties could be a superposition of states.

I don't have (yet ?) the understanding of the concepts of LQG to determine whether or not this would be a silly way to formulate the theory or not. Searching for it on Google, I found a few pages mentionning both terms in bold above but always as two distinct models (or even in different articles of a same site).

Has there been some studies on formulating loop quantum gravity as a cellular automaton ? Would it even make sense ?

Comment: Related: [Relativistic Cellular Automata](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/887/50583), [Can cellular automata be reconcilied with quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19647/50583)

Comment: CA aren't traditionally thought to interact with cells that aren't adjacent, but that doesn't mean it can't be done, though not sure if you could get anything remotely similar to a real world model for the complexity involved.

Comment: @Neil: page 14 of the lectures, he talks about locality of the transition amplitude that I understood (maybe wrongly) as the possibility to consider only neighbours and as something compatible with cellular automaton transitions. But again, I don't understand much this part yet ... so I may have been completely misleaded by the similar term 'transition' and my previous idea that the foam was looking like a CA :-)

Comment: I'm seeing the issue from the perspective of a physics enthusiast and professional programmer, so I couldn't tell you honestly.  If the cells directly interact with many neighbors and not just say 8 surrounding cells, calculation begins to be very impractical at larger levels very quickly.  :/

Comment: My question is not necessarly to implement it, but to wonder if there could be an equivalent (or approaching) formulation in a way that would be easier to understand (at least for me).